# Pdf view file on codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, codeigniter

Please i have some pdf files saved on uploads folder and i want to view the files, i have a code but whenever i click on the view button, it returns 404 page not found. I have tried to call the download function and also the viewfile function
.
Below is the view file code
.

```
<div class="box-body">
                <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php $status = TRUE; $k = 0; if(isset($activitiesmedia[$activity->activitiesID])) { foreach ($activitiesmedia[$activity->activitiesID] as $attachment) { ?>
                            <?php if(count($activitiesmedia[$activity->activitiesID]) == 2) { $status = FALSE; ?>
                                <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                                    <span class="activity-icon-box"><i class="fa <?=isset($activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]) ? $activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]->fa_icon : ''?>"></i></span>
                                    <img style="width: 100%;height:300px" class="img-responsive pad" src="<?=base_url("uploads/activities/$attachment->attachment"); ?>" alt="Photo">
                                   <a href="<?=base_url('Activities/viewfiles/'.$attachment->attachment)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            <?php $k++; } elseif(count($activitiesmedia[$activity->activitiesID]) > 1) { if($status) { ?>
                                <div class="col-md-4 no-padding">
                                    <span class="activity-icon-box"><i class="fa <?=isset($activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]) ? $activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]->fa_icon : ''?>"></i></span>
                                    <img style="width: 100%;height:200px" class="img-responsive pad" src="<?=base_url("uploads/activities/$attachment->attachment"); ?>" alt="Photo">
                                    <a href="<?=base_url('Activities/viewfiles/'.$attachment->attachment)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            <?php } } else { ?>
                                <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                                    <span class="activity-icon-box"><i class="fa <?=isset($activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]) ? $activitiescategories[$activity->activitiescategoryID]->fa_icon : ''?>"></i></span>
                                    <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 450px;" class="img-responsive pad" src="<?=base_url("uploads/activities/$attachment->attachment"); ?>" alt="Photo">
                                    <a href="<?=base_url('Activities/viewfiles/'.$attachment->attachment)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
                                   ?>
                                </div>
```

**Below is the controller**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
 class Activities extends Admin_Controller

{    public function __construct()

{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("activities_m");
    $this->load->model("activitiescategory_m");
    $this->load->model("activitiesstudent_m");
    $this->load->model("activitiesmedia_m");
    $this->load->model("activitiescomment_m");
    $this->load->model("studentrelation_m");
    $this->load->model("classes_m");
    $this->load->model("section_m");
    $language = $this->session->userdata('lang');
    $this->lang->load('activities', $language);
    $this->load->helper('date');
}

public function index()
{
    $schoolyearID = $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID');
    $loginuserID  = $this->session->userdata('loginuserID');
    $usertypeID   = $this->session->userdata('usertypeID');

    $this->data['user']                 = getAllSelectUser();
    $this->data['userID']               = $loginuserID;
    $this->data['usertypeID']           = $usertypeID;
    $this->data['activitiescategories'] = pluck($this->activitiescategory_m->get_activitiescategory(), 'obj', 'activitiescategoryID');
    $this->data['activitiesmedia']      = pluck_multi_array($this->activitiesmedia_m->get_activitiesmedia(), 'obj', 'activitiesID');
    $this->data['activitiescomments']   = pluck_multi_array($this->activitiescomment_m->get_order_by_activitiescomment(array('schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID)), 'obj', 'activitiesID');

    if ($usertypeID == 2) {
        $students                 = $this->studentrelation_m->get_order_by_student(['srschoolyearID' => $schoolyearID]);
        $studentArray             = pluck($students, 'studentID');
        $this->data['activities'] = $this->activities_m->get_where_in_activities($studentArray, 'studentID', array('schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID));
    } elseif ($usertypeID == 3) {
        $this->data['activities'] = $this->activities_m->get_order_by_activities(array('schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID, 'studentID' => $loginuserID));
    } elseif ($usertypeID == 4) {
        $students                 = $this->studentrelation_m->get_order_by_student(['srschoolyearID' => $schoolyearID]);
        $studentArray             = pluck($students, 'studentID');
        $this->data['activities'] = $this->activities_m->get_where_in_activities($studentArray, 'studentID', array('schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID));
    } else {
        $this->data['activities'] = $this->activities_m->get_order_by_activities(array('schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID));
    }

    if (($this->data['siteinfos']->school_year == $schoolyearID) || ($usertypeID == 1)) {
        if ($_POST) {
            $id = htmlentities(escapeString($this->uri->segment(3)));
            if ((int) $id) {
                if ($_POST['comment']) {
                    $array['activitiesID'] = $id;
                    $array['comment']      = $this->input->post('comment');
                    $array['schoolyearID'] = $schoolyearID;
                    $array['userID']       = $this->session->userdata("loginuserID");
                    $array['usertypeID']   = $this->session->userdata("usertypeID");
                    $array['create_date']  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $this->activitiescomment_m->insert_activitiescomment($array);
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line("menu_success"));
                    redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->data["subview"] = "activities/index";
    $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
}

public function add()
{
    $schoolyearID = $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID');
    if (($this->data['siteinfos']->school_year == $schoolyearID) || ($this->session->userdata('usertypeID') == 1)) {

        if($this->session->userdata('usertypeID') == 3 || $this->session->userdata('usertypeID') == 4) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->lang->line('menu_permission_not_allowed'));
            redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
        }            

        $this->data['headerassets'] = array(
            'css' => array(
                'assets/datepicker/datepicker.css',
                'assets/timepicker/timepicker.css',
                'assets/select2/css/select2.css',
                'assets/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.css',
                'assets/tooltipster/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css',
            ),
            'js'  => array(
                'assets/datepicker/datepicker.js',
                'assets/select2/select2.js',
                'assets/tooltipster/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js',
                'assets/timepicker/timepicker.js',
            ),
        );
        $categoryID             = htmlentities(escapeString($this->uri->segment(3)));
        $this->data['classes']  = $this->classes_m->get_classes();
        $this->data['sections'] = [];
        $this->data['students'] = [];
        if ((int) $categoryID) {
            $this->data['activities_categories'] = $this->activitiescategory_m->get_activitiescategory();
            if ($_POST) {

                $classesID = $this->input->post("classesID");
                $sectionID = $this->input->post("sectionID");
                $studentID = $this->input->post("studentID");

                if ((int) $classesID) {
                    $this->data['sections'] = $this->section_m->get_order_by_section(array('classesID' => $classesID));

                    $qArray['srclassesID'] = $classesID;
                    if ((int) $sectionID) {
                        $qArray['srsectionID'] = $sectionID;
                    }
                    $qArray['srschoolyearID'] = $schoolyearID;
                    $this->data['students']   = $this->studentrelation_m->get_order_by_student($qArray);
                }

                $rules = $this->rules();
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                    $this->data["subview"] = "activities/add";
                    $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
                } else {
                    $array = array(
                        "classesID"            => $classesID,
                        "sectionID"            => $sectionID,
                        "studentID"            => $studentID,
                        "description"          => $this->input->post("description"),
                        "activitiescategoryID" => $categoryID,
                        "schoolyearID"         => $schoolyearID,
                        "usertypeID"           => $this->session->userdata('usertypeID'),
                        "userID"               => $this->session->userdata('loginuserID'),
                    );
                    if ($this->input->post("time_to") != "0:00") {
                        $array["time_to"] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post("time_to")));
                    }
                    if ($this->input->post("time_from") != "0:00") {
                        $array["time_from"] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post("time_from")));
                    }
                    if ($this->input->post("time_at") != "0:00") {
                        $array["time_at"] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post("time_at")));
                    }

                    $array["create_date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $array["modify_date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                    $id = $this->activities_m->insert_activities($array);

                    if ($id) {
                        if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
                            $filesCount = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
                            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                                $_FILES['attach']['name']     = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i];
                                $_FILES['attach']['type']     = $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$i];
                                $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i];
                                $_FILES['attach']['error']    = $_FILES['attachment']['error'][$i];
                                $_FILES['attach']['size']     = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$i];

                                $uploadPath              = 'uploads/activities';
                                $config['upload_path']   = $uploadPath;
                                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|PDF';

                                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                                if ($this->upload->do_upload('attach')) {
                                    $fileData                       = $this->upload->data();
                                    $uploadData[$i]['attachment']   = $fileData['file_name'];
                                    $uploadData[$i]['activitiesID'] = $id;
                                    $uploadData[$i]['create_date']  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                                }
                            }
                            if (!empty($uploadData)) {
                                $this->activitiesmedia_m->insert_batch_activitiesmedia($uploadData);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('menu_success'));
                    redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
                }
            } else {
                $this->data["subview"] = "activities/add";
                $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
            }
        } else {
            $this->data["subview"] = "activities/add";
            $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
        }
    } else {
        $this->data["subview"] = "error";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}

public function delete()
{
    if (($this->data['siteinfos']->school_year == $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID')) || ($this->session->userdata('usertypeID') == 1)) {
        $id         = htmlentities(escapeString($this->uri->segment(3)));
        $usertypeID = $this->session->userdata('usertypeID');
        $userID     = $this->session->userdata('loginuserID');

        if ((int) $id) {
            $activities = $this->activities_m->get_activities($id);
            if (($usertypeID == $activities->usertypeID && $userID == $activities->userID) || ($usertypeID == 1)) {
                $this->activities_m->delete_activities($id);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('menu_success'));
            }
            redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
        } else {
            redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
        }
    } else {
        $this->data["subview"] = "error";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}

public function delete_comment()
{
    if (($this->data['siteinfos']->school_year == $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID')) || ($this->session->userdata('usertypeID') == 1)) {
        $id         = htmlentities(escapeString($this->uri->segment(3)));
        $usertypeID = $this->session->userdata('usertypeID');
        $userID     = $this->session->userdata('loginuserID');

        if ((int) $id) {
            $comment    = $this->activitiescomment_m->get_activitiescomment($id);
            $activities = $this->activities_m->get_activities($comment->activitiesID);
            if (($usertypeID == $activities->usertypeID && $userID == $activities->userID) || ($usertypeID == 1)) {
                $this->activitiescomment_m->delete_activitiescomment($id);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('menu_success'));
            }
            redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
        } else {
            redirect(base_url("activities/index"));
        }
    } else {
        $this->data["subview"] = "error";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}

protected function rules()
{
    $rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'classesID',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("menu_classes"),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_unique_data',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'sectionID',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("menu_section"),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_unique_data',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'studentID',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("menu_student"),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_unique_data',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'description',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("activities_description"),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'attachment',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("attachment"),
            'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'time_from',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("activities_time_from"),
            'rules' => 'trim|max_length[10]|xss_clean',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'time_to',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("activities_time_to"),
            'rules' => 'trim|max_length[10]|xss_clean',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'time_at',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("activities_time_at"),
            'rules' => 'trim|max_length[10]|xss_clean',
        ),
    );
    return $rules;
}

public function get_section()
{
    $classesID = $this->input->post('classesID');
    if ((int) $classesID) {
        $sections = $this->section_m->get_order_by_section(array('classesID' => $classesID));
        echo "<option value='0'>" . $this->lang->line("menu_please_select") . "</option>";
        foreach ($sections as $section) {
            echo "<option value=" . $section->sectionID . ">" . $section->section . "</option>";
        }
    }
}

public function get_student()
{
    $classesID = $this->input->post('classesID');
    if ((int) $classesID) {
        $schoolyearID          = $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID');
        $qArray['srclassesID'] = $classesID;
        $sectionID             = $this->input->post('sectionID');
        if ((int) $sectionID) {
            $qArray['srsectionID'] = $sectionID;
        }
        $qArray['srschoolyearID'] = $schoolyearID;

        $students = $this->studentrelation_m->get_order_by_student($qArray);
        echo "<option value='0'>" . $this->lang->line("menu_please_select") . "</option>";
        foreach ($students as $student) {
            echo "<option value=" . $student->studentID . ">" . $student->srname . "</option>";
        }
    }

   public function viewfile(){
    $fname = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $tofile= realpath("uploads/activities/".$fname);
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    readfile($tofile);
}

public function unique_data($data)
{
    if ($data == 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message("unique_data", "The %s field is required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

**Below is the Model**

```
class Activitiesmedia_m extends MY_Model {

protected $_table_name = 'activitiesmedia';
protected $_primary_key = 'activitiesmediaID';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = "activitiesID asc";

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_activitiesmedia($array=NULL, $signal=FALSE) {
    $query = parent::get($array, $signal);
    return $query;
}

function get_order_by_activitiesmedia($array=NULL) {
    $query = parent::get_order_by($array);
    return $query;
}

function get_single_activitiesmedia($array=NULL) {
    $query = parent::get_single($array);
    return $query;
}
function download($id){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('files',array('id'=>$id));
        return $query->row_array();
}

function insert_activitiesmedia($array) {
    $id = parent::insert($array);
    return $id;
}

function insert_batch_activitiesmedia($array) {
    $insert = $this->db->insert_batch($this->_table_name, $array);
    return $insert ? true:false;
}

function update_activitiesmedia($data, $id = NULL) {
    parent::update($data, $id);
    return $id;
}

public function delete_activitiesmedia($id){
    parent::delete($id);
}
}
```

Below is the file upload.php

```
                   <?php
                    if(form_error('attachment'))
                        echo "<div class='form-group has-error' >";
                    else
                        echo "<div class='form-group' >";
                ?>
                    <label for="attachment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        <?=$this->lang->line("attachment")?>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input id="fileupload" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="attachment[]"/>

                    </div>

                    <span class="col-sm-4">
                        <?php echo form_error('attachment'); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<?=$this->lang->line("add_activities")?>" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer clearfix">
    <div id="dvPreview"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the pdf files with iframe tag in html.

`<iframe src="path/to/your/file"></iframe>
//the path can be made dinamic from javascript`

Comment: Hello @Bogdan, Thank you for the answer, I tried that and I got the url you submitted has disallowed characters. What can i do ?

Comment: https://hoststud.com/resources/error-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters-in-codeigniter.420/ try this

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan, Done that, not getting that error anymore but it's still showing page not found 404 error.

Comment: Check to see if you give the right path to the file

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a library like Dompdf to create a file pdf, of couse you can create a new page and then see your data on the page like pdf.
pls have a look: 
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: Hello @Chu van, thanks for the response, the issue is that when i upload the pdf file, i am unable to view it or download it. Anytime i click on the file to download, it shows page not found.

Comment: sr, I have found an example about read file pdf  and also you can download it . pls have a look
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNbQL0x1xiU